# Übersetzung von "Take another guess!"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> Wrong! **Take another guess!**

Wie kann man das ins Deutsche übersetzen? [Reverso Dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-german/guess) schlägt *Vermutung*, *Annahme* und *Schätzung* als Übersetzungen des Substantivs *guess* vor, aber ich glaube, dass keines hier gut passt. Die [Google-Übersetzung](https://translate.google.com/#auto/de/Wrong!%20Take%20another%20guess!) ist

> Falsch! Nehmen Sie eine andere Vermutung!

Das klingt viel zu formell, auch wenn man stattdessen "Nimm eine andere Vermutung" sagen könnte. Es gibt andere Phrasen, mit denen man den Satz ausdrücken kann, wie

> Noch mal!
>
> Noch ein Versuch!
>
> Rate noch mal!

aber keine dieser Alternativen benutzt *guess* als Substantiv. Kann man den Satz direkter übersetzen?

Comment: Warum direkt übersetzen? Eine Wort-für-Wort-Entsprechung kann Dir auch ein Lexikon-Lookup-Algorithmus liefern. Wir brauchen aber menschliche Übersetzer (und Support-Foren), weil die direkte Übersetzung **nicht** die richtige ist.

Comment: @KilianFoth Nicht *direkt* übersetzen, sondern *direkter*. Ich verstehe, dass es solche Übersetzungen manchmal nicht gibt, aber es ist schwer zu wissen ohne zu fragen. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Das Verb *raten* würd für gewöhnlich ins Englische übersetzt mit

> to guess
>   to have a guess
>   to take a guess

Daher wäre die beste Übersetzung:

> Falsch! Rate noch mal!

Eine geeignete und gebräuchliche Formulierung, welche ein Substantiv mit vergleichbarer Bedeutung verwendet, ist mir nicht bekannt.

Answer (score 8):

Nein, das kann man wortwörtlich **nicht** übersetzen. Allgemein gilt: Wörtliche Übersetzungen nur, wenn die Zielsprache zufällig das gleiche Muster verwendet.

Vergesse auch bitte Google Translate! Weder "nehmen" noch "Vermutung" ist im Kontext richtig.

Wie [von Burki vorgeschlagen](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26899/1224), greif zum Verb *raten*. Eine gängige Alternative (ganz ohne *guess* jedoch) ist:

> Versuch's nochmal. (Try again.)

Und wenn's ein Substantiv sein soll:

> Du hast noch einen Versuch.

Comment: Ich finde den Ansatz über *versuch* nicht ganz so geeignet, da *take another guess* impliziert, der so angesprochene verfüge nicht über die Fähigkeiten, die gestellte Aufgabe geziehlt zu lösen.

Comment: @Burki Ob das wirklich so ist, müsste man mal auf ELU fragen, aber persönlich empfinde ich das nicht so. Was die deutschen Varianten angeht (deine Übersetzung und mein Vorschlag), sehe ich übrigens auch keinen Unterschied.

Comment: @Tarok Durchaus ein deutsches Wort, [Pattern](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pattern) ;)

Comment: `Versuch's noch mal!` I would not use "wrong" in this context, because Germans never misdo :)